# File exists and IS directory, but listFiles() returns null

Tags: java, android, file, io, file-permissions

[The documentation for `File.listFiles()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) suggests that `null` will ONLY be returned in the case that the file calling it is not a directory.

I have the following:

```
String dir = "/storage/emulated/0";
File f = new File(dir);
Log.v("Files",f.exists()+"");
Log.v("Files",f.isDirectory()+"");
Log.v("Files",f.listFiles()+"");
```

The log reads:

```
true
true
null
```

For some reason, `listFiles(`) is returning `null` even though the `File` is recognized as a valid directory. I'm not super familiar with Android file hierarchy behavior, so I would guess the problem lies in there.

For reference, I'm debugging on my Moto X, and results are the same whether the phone is plugged in to my computer or not - so I don't think it has to do with mounting when plugged in.

Comment: Isn't it a permissions issue? Does a normal user have access to that dir?

Comment: have you tried putting a file in that directory? Seems to me that what the documentation actually suggests is that it WILL be null if it isn't a directory but it would also return null if there are no actual Files in there

Comment: @DigCamara Well, in Java, File includes directories - and there are directories in that folder.

Comment: @Peterdk I switched to /sdcard, which points to the same thing, and I think is open to users..?, and got the same results.

Comment: What does [`File#canRead()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) tell you? (If that is false and I'm pretty sure it is, you will get `null` when you try to read the content of the directoy)

Comment: I'm suffering from the same permission issue except I am the admin user for this PC and I'm not attempting to access any specially protected directorys... I can't understand why my program doesn't automatically have them when I run it, it should list files in its own directory when run...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

For those with this problem, add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Problem solved :D

EDIT: If this does not work just make sure if path is correct

Comment: +5 for this answer! I wonder why there is no error saying I don't have this permission in logcat?

Comment: On Marshmallow+ you need to call the following as well: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);

Comment: IHeartAndroid: I was trying to copy and paste this code and it wasn't working until I realized you're requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE instead of READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as the answer is doing.

Comment: as tamo stated below (as of Android 10 and later) it is now REQUIRED to include android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your manifest !!!!

Answer (score 58):

In addition to other answers and comments, I'd suggest you check whether you need

```xml
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in your manifest. [It seems that some recent apis need it.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped)

Anyway, [zapl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null#comment31030588_20714058) is rather short but quite insightful.
You can "ls -ld" the directory on the device (via "adb shell" or some other shells).
If you have "r" permission on the directory, you can call listFiles(). Otherwise, it returns null. Note that you can access files under the unreadable directory if you know the file names and have "x" permission on the directory.
You can know who you are by "whoami" and "groups" commands.

Comment: Needed for Android 10

Comment: requestLegacyExternalStorage is meant to be transitional and is not supported in Android 11 when you build for SDK 30: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app

Answer (score 28):

For android **version 23 or higher**, you need to give **run time permission** programmatically in onresume method as below,

```
public final String[] EXTERNAL_PERMS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

public final int EXTERNAL_REQUEST = 138;

requestForPermission();

public boolean requestForPermission() {

    boolean isPermissionOn = true;
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        if (!canAccessExternalSd()) {
            isPermissionOn = false;
            requestPermissions(EXTERNAL_PERMS, EXTERNAL_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    return isPermissionOn;
}

public boolean canAccessExternalSd() {
    return (hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
}

private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm));

}
```

Comment: I am having this problem with internal storage

Comment: This solution is the only one that worked for me. Tested in Nougat 7.0

Answer (score 14):

For those with this problem you to give read permission, add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

and you should also grant permission from

Settings > Apps > *"Your app name"* > Permissions > storage

Comment: This is the right solution in my case. It doesn't require changing code and it is applicable to all the apps that work on Lollipop, but are not adapted to the Marshmallow's new concept of [granting permissions at run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: What about for Internal storage?

Answer (score 9):

From the File 'listFiles' method documentation: Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So perhaps an I/O error occurred.  Check the permissions on that directory, does the user running the java program have the permission to read that directory?  If not, there is your answer.  If they do, then perhaps the directory is empty.

BTW you should not use +"" to convert something to a string, it's a bad practice since it's slower than String.valueOf.  I would use apache's StringUtils to join that array into a string, but that requires adding that jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the permission in manifest `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`  and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

1. List item

Add this in your AndroidManifest.xml <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .../>
It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

@tamo's answer resolved my issue, i compile exoplayer on ANQ, and set :

build.gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

manifest.xml :

```
  <application
  android:name="com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.ExoPlayerDemoApplication"
  android:label="@string/application_name"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:largeHeap="true"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

i check android develop site, it's already explain this :
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility

if you target API 29 or higher, just follow google's setting.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that for some reason the android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" attribute was not allowing the app to read /sdcard/ on a specific device.

As I needed to do only a quick test, I removed the sharedUserId attribute, tested and added it back.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are asking the permission for reading the external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if you want you can the Dexter library for asking permission it is very easy to ask permission using the dexter library

here is the link to that

[Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

then after that add the following tag in the *<application* tag in the *manifest*

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

then the listFiles() function will not return null array

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem in java but not in android where i am reading config file with path in quotes. I solved my issue with just removing quotes

So you can do it by String replace function or give it without quotes

String someString= "C:\path";
someString=someString.replace("\"","");

Answer (score -1):

In the manifest file at the `<uses-permission .... >` section, add this line `android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`. I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't this just a repeat of the existing answers?