# ListView crashes app

Tags: android, listview

Trying to list all files in a directory, the directory contains only Audio files, But however when I run the App on device, app crashes, here is the main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<String> myList;
File file;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listerX);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File( directory + "/myAppCache/" );
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.
}
```

As I haven't tried ListView before, this seems alien to me, Other questions here too doesnt seems to solve my problem. 
Here is my logcat as well:

```
> 07-15 13:09:52.067  17443-17443/antivirus.dc.lab.texttospeech E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: antivirus.dc.lab.texttospeech, PID: 17443
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{antivirus.dc.lab.texttospeech/antivirus.dc.lab.texttospeech.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at antivirus.dc.lab.texttospeech.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: your `list` is null that's why you getting error

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null

Comment: @VladimirS Yes it works, +1 for the help

Answer (score 0):

Because your `list []` is null . You can not get length of `null`.
Change your code to

```
File list[] = file.listFiles();
if (list != null)
{
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answering , But it was not due to that. I tested the code in a new project, so I forgot to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException error because your list is not correctly initializing and it always returns null .

First you need to initialize it in correct way so you can read it .

Hadi Mohammadi's answer is incomplete . With this way it will prevent you to get NullPointerException error but still it will be null so that's why you need to focus on that .