# Android refuses to read files

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to load all the mp3 files to an array, but android keeps showing this error :  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`, the error is in this line :  `if(path.isDirectory() && path.listFiles().length > 0)`

I added these two permission lines to my manifest files, but there was no effect :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

my function is initially called by : `locateSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`

and this is my function to iterate the full device :

```
 private void locateSongs(File path) {
        if(path.isDirectory() && path.listFiles().length > 0){
            File files[] = path.listFiles();
            for(File f : files){
                locateSongs(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            }
        }else if(path.isFile() && path.getName().contains(".mp3")){ // // TODO: 2/5/2016 add more types other than mp3
            MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            metaRetriver.setDataSource(path.getAbsolutePath());

            Song newSong = new Song();
            newSong.setAlbum(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            newSong.setArtist(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            newSong.setAuthor(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR));
            newSong.setName(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            newSong.setBitRate(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE));
            newSong.setGenre(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
            newSong.setDataSourse(path.getAbsolutePath());
            newSong.setDuration(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

            byte[] art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            newSong.setImage(songImage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null

Comment: Also `metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture()` [allowed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getEmbeddedPicture()) to return null. When it happens you'll get similar error.

Comment: I've added the permission request in the manifest file, also I have tried adding the try and catch, but the error is in the first if condition

Comment: So `path` is null or `path.listFiles()` returns null. Check both for null before use and do not use if it is null but display a toast to the user saying so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who tried to help, I've found the solution, the problem was due to using Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) emulator, the problem is solved here : 
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html