# How can i fetch Whatsapp user's status and display in my android app?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I want to fetch live status from Whatsapp into my android activity. Is it possible  to do this? If yes your guidance will be really appreciated.

[Please see the image i want to make an  activity containing all the statuses. Just like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhJYA.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: check if they have an API

Comment: When you click on someone's status, it gets stored in your cache memory. See here: https://trickybell.com/save-whatsapp-status-without-taking-screenshots/

Comment: did you got any solution?

Comment: have you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 6):

WhatsApp store showed status to your device memory or sd card **WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses** folder. This folder is hidden. You can fetch data from there.

Answer (score 4):

**For Kotlin Lover**

```
   companion object {
    const val WHATSAPP_STATUS_FOLDER_PATH = "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/"
   }

   fun getImagePath(): ArrayList<String> {
    // image path list
    val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    // fetching file path from storage
    val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + WHATSAPP_STATUS_FOLDER_PATH)
    val listFile = file.listFiles()

    if (listFile != null && listFile.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Arrays.sort(listFile, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE)
    }

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (imgFile in listFile) {
            if (
                imgFile.name.endsWith(".jpg")
                || imgFile.name.endsWith(".jpeg")
                || imgFile.name.endsWith(".png")
            ) {
                val model = imgFile.absolutePath
                list.add(model)
            }
        }
    }

    // return imgPath List
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**There You Go**

```
    final String WHATSAPP_STATUSES_LOCATION = "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
    RecyclerView mRecyclerViewMediaList = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMedia);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerViewMediaList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    ListAdapter recyclerViewMediaAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, this.getListFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + WHATSAPP_STATUSES_LOCATION)));
    mRecyclerViewMediaList.setAdapter(recyclerViewMediaAdapter);



  private ArrayList<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files;
    files = parentDir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            Log.e("check", file.getName());
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") ||
                    file.getName().endsWith(".gif") ||
                    file.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                if (!inFiles.contains(file))
                    inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
 public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    final Context context;
    final ArrayList<File> modelFeedArrayList;
    private static final String DIRECTORY_TO_SAVE_MEDIA_NOW = "/WhatsappStatus/";

    public ListAdapter(Context context, final ArrayList<File> modelFeedArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelFeedArrayList = modelFeedArrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_media_row_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        File currentFile = modelFeedArrayList.get(position);

        if (currentFile.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp4")) {
            holder.cardViewImageMedia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.cardViewVideoMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            holder.videoViewVideoMedia.setVideoURI(video);
            holder.videoViewVideoMedia.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                holder.videoViewVideoMedia.start();
            });
        } else {
            holder.cardViewImageMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cardViewVideoMedia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            holder.imageViewImageMedia.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelFeedArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageViewImageMedia;
        VideoView videoViewVideoMedia;
        CardView cardViewVideoMedia;
        CardView cardViewImageMedia;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewImageMedia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImageMedia);
            videoViewVideoMedia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewVideoMedia);
            cardViewVideoMedia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewVideoMedia);
            cardViewImageMedia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewImageMedia);

        }
    }
}
```

**Row XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewVideoMedia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoViewVideoMedia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewImageMedia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewImageMedia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

add to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



 <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Android 10 File.listFiles() may return null, see [File exists and IS directory, but listFiles() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373617/18858169   checked this might be solution of Android 10 File.listFiles() may return null

Answer (score 1):

Well all the content of WhatsApp user status are locally stored in **/WhatsApp/.Statuses**  folder except text Statuses. You can simply load all the images and videos that are in the folder in grid view and give options to save and share.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem of** `path` **and** `file not found` **solved with this.**

**You can try this Path. it may be helpful for you.**

For `Android-10` and above

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
```

Below `Android-10` Version

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
```

Comment: not working in android 11 and 12