# Unable to run app in emulator with API 29 android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app run normally in the emulator with API 28. But when I run the app in the emulator with API 29 it shows

[image]

It does not only show keeps stopping in the emulator. I tried to install it on mobile and it also shows the same error.

The log shows this error like this:

```
2020-02-14 19:48:12.922 20370-20370/? E/stickerappmake: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-02-14 19:48:15.326 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:15.326 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:15.385 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:15.385 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:17.138 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:17.139 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:17.243 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:17.243 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:19.984 20370-20464/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:19.984 20370-20464/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:20.048 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:20.048 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:20.059 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:20.063 20370-20454/com.testdev.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-14 19:48:22.727 20370-20370/com.testdev.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testdev.appname, PID: 20370
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.testdev.appname.activities.CreateFragment.loadStickersCreated(CreateFragment.java:52)
        at com.testdev.appname.activities.CreateFragment.onCreateView(CreateFragment.java:88)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I see there some problems with the java code in CreateFragment.java. And the java code is like below:
The CreateFragment.java code:

package com.devname.appname.activities;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView;
import com.devname.appname.helpers.Admob;
import com.sangcomz.fishbun.FishBun;
import com.sangcomz.fishbun.adapter.image.impl.GlideAdapter;
import com.sangcomz.fishbun.define.Define;
import com.devname.appname.R;
import com.devname.appname.backgroundRemover.CutOut;
import com.devname.appname.helpers.Constants;
import com.devname.appname.utils.FileUtils;
import com.devname.appname.utils.StickerPacksManager;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreateFragment extends Fragment {
    ImagesGridAdapter imagesGridAdapter;
    View view;

    public CreateFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ArrayList<Uri> loadStickersCreated() {
        String directoryPath = Constants.STICKERS_CREATED_DIRECTORY_PATH;
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        ArrayList<Uri> images = new ArrayList<>();
        if (directory.exists()) {
            File[] stickersImages = directory.listFiles();
            for (File f : stickersImages) {
                if (f.isFile() && (f.getName().contains(".png") || f.getName().contains(".PNG"))) {
                    images.add(Uri.fromFile((f)));
                }
            }
        } else {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
       // verifyStickersCount();
        return images;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
        Admob.createLoadBanner(getContext(), view);
        view.findViewById(R.id.create_sticker).setOnClickListener(v -> FishBun.with(getActivity())
                .setImageAdapter(new GlideAdapter())
                .setMaxCount(1)
                .exceptGif(true)
                .setMinCount(1)
                .setActionBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), false)
                .setActionBarTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                .startAlbum());

        RecyclerView gridview = view.findViewById(R.id.stickers_created_grid);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(), 3);
        gridview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        imagesGridAdapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(view.getContext(), loadStickersCreated());
        gridview.setAdapter(imagesGridAdapter);
        verifyStickersCount();
        return view;
    }

    public void verifyStickersCount() {
        View linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.no_stickers_icon);
        if (imagesGridAdapter == null || imagesGridAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

        context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("TESTTTTTT",requestCode+"");
        if (requestCode == CutOut.CUTOUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.d("TESTTTTTT :::::",requestCode+"");
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    String imagePath_intent = data.getStringExtra("imagePath");
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath_intent));

                    Log.d("TESTTTTTT ::::: He",imageUri+"");
                    String stickerName = FileUtils.generateRandomIdentifier();
                    Uri imagePath = Uri.parse(Constants.STICKERS_CREATED_DIRECTORY_PATH + stickerName + ".PNG");
                    StickerPacksManager.createStickerImageFile(imageUri, imagePath, getActivity(), Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG);
                    addImageToGallery(imagePath.getPath(), getActivity());
                    imagesGridAdapter.uries = loadStickersCreated();
                    imagesGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sticker created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    verifyStickersCount();
                    break;
                case CutOut.CUTOUT_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE:
                    Exception ex = CutOut.getError(data);
                    Log.d("TESTTTTTT :::::",ex+"::DDD");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("User cancelled the CutOut screen");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == Define.ALBUM_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ArrayList<Uri> uries;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                uries = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Define.INTENT_PATH);
                CutOut.activity().src(uries.get(0)).intro().start(getActivity());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImagesGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder> {
        public ArrayList<Uri> uries = new ArrayList<>();
        Context context;

        public ImagesGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Uri> uries) {
            this.uries = uries;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            final Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sticker_created_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ImageViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageAdapter, int index) {
            imageAdapter.imageView.setImageURI(uries.get(index));
            imageAdapter.imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageAdapter.imageView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, imageAdapter.imageView);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.sticker_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                     /*  case R.id.add_to_exist_stickerpack:
                            addToStickerPack(index);
                            break;*/
                        case R.id.delete_sticker:
                            this.deleteSticker(index);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                popupMenu.show();
                return false;
            });
        }

        void deleteSticker(int index) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Deleting")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this sticker?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                        Uri uri = uries.get(index);
                        FileUtils.deleteFile(uri.getPath(),context);
                        uries.remove(index);
                        notifyItemRemoved(index);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        verifyStickersCount();
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }

         void addToStickerPack(int index) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddToStickerPackActivity.class);
            intent.setData(uries.get(index));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return uries.size();
        }
    }

    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SimpleDraweeView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_created_image);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the error says it all -> Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: can you add your permissions here from manifest please ?

Comment: here are permissions from manifest:


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in directory path in Constants.STICKERS_CREATED_DIRECTORY_PATH. In Constant.java there some codes like below:

```
public final static String STICKERS_CREATED_DIRECTORY_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WA Stickers/My Created/";
```

then I specify the directory path

```
public final static String STICKERS_CREATED_DIRECTORY_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/storage/emulated/0/WA Stickers/My Created/";
```

It works. Thanks for your answers.

Edited:
It works only in emulator. I tried installing in real device but the app force closed.

Edited:
problem solved. I installed the apk with different apk signer from previous apk that is already installed. so everything runs normally with codes above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's read your error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

some array of you is `null` and you still try to get the `length` of it.

> at com.testdev.appname.activities.CreateFragment.loadStickersCreated(CreateFragment.java:52)

and it even tells you, in which line you will find the error

```
File[] stickersImages = directory.listFiles();
```

stickerImages seems to be null.

```
for (File f : stickersImages) {/*...*/}
```

it tries to read from `stickerImages`, which is `null` and therefore this `Exception` is thrown.

Comment: 2. add this to AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: read here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null

Comment: thanks for you answer. the problem is in the derectory path..

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments these are your app permissions in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

you need to add read permissions to in order to get the files from directory so apply below [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also you should check this permission in run-time too because the user might deny it and this error will show again, you can do the check as below :

```
public boolean readExtertalStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int result = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

For more details you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)