# Why can't I read from Local Storage after swapping code to another project

Tags: android, file

I have code that works to read files from the users downloads folder
This worked fine in my old project (and still does)
Swapped code to new project with a latter unrelated library and it fails...
Manifest contains the SAME read and write permissions
Still using same android api target 29, same dev phone is android 8.0
code is

```
private void chooseAreaFromLocal() {
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] files = mapsFolder.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename != null
                    && (filename.endsWith(".ghz") || filename
                    .endsWith("-gh"));
        }
    });
    Collections.addAll(nameList, files);
```

Fails on last line because the List "files" is empty, but it most certainly isn't, there are files in that directory.
Confused because code hasn't changed and manifest hasn't changed , sdk hasn't changed

mapsfolder (in my case )is "/storage/emulated/0/Download/polyline/store"

Code that determines mapsfolder is

```
boolean greaterOrEqKitkat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    if (greaterOrEqKitkat) {
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            logUser("not usable without external storage");
            return;
        }

        mapsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/polyline/store/");
    } else
        mapsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/polyline/store/");

    if (!mapsFolder.exists())
        mapsFolder.mkdirs();
```

compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 29

What other factors could have changed that would limit my ability to read from this folder?

Comment: Maybe you have this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null

Comment: On 29==Q that folder should never be readable.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs().

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, 
Phone (Huawei Nova 2i) had cancelled all granted permissions on this app when user data was cleared.

Comment: That is the default behavior of Android system and is same in any device out there with Android. Whenever, an app's data/cache is cleared, every permissions is set to not granted and previously granted permissions are revoked, also if any permission's status is changed from the app's info screen while app is running, then the app restarts.