# Android : unable to list /storage/emulated/0 files despite permissions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-permissions, android-gallery, android-file

I have the following code to handle storage permissions :

```
private void getGalleryPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getGalleryPermission: checking permissions.");
        String[] permissions = { WRITE_STORAGE, READ_STORAGE };
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), WRITE_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getGalleryPermission: write storage is granted.");
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), READ_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getGalleryPermission: read storage is granted.");
                setupRecyclerView();
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "getGalleryPermission: asking to read the storage.");
                requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getGalleryPermission: asking to write the storage.");
            requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: request code " + requestCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: request code is correct.");
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                    if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Don't have permission to access the Gallery !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Setup the gallery once the permissions are granted
                setupRecyclerView();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am testing this code on several of my phones, and it's working perfectly. However, on my Huawei, the `listFiles()` method returns `null` on the `/storage/emulated/0 directory`.

I have checked in the phone Settings + in logs, and the storage permissions are granted (like on other working phones).

What can prevent the files from being read despite granted permissions ?

On some phones, is it possible that the /storage/emulated/0 is not the correct directory to target to get all gallery files ?

PS : i have checked the directory from the Files application in my phone and it's not empty (DCIM, etc.... are inside).

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please add your `listFiles` method, I want to test your code in my Huawei device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the Huawei device which returns `null` running Android 10? It seems that for that path Android returns `null` since API 29. You might want to check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null).

Comment: this is the real answer but it was in the link you provided me : <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"