# Android ListFiles returns null

Tags: c#, android, android-external-storage, uno-platform

I'm using UnoPlatform to create an Android application and I'm looking for read Directories and Files into external usb stick.
This is the code I'm using, but after a lot of attempts following this link

[File exists and IS directory, but listFiles() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714058/file-exists-and-is-directory-but-listfiles-returns-null)

I'm not able to get Directories or files, because the method ListFiles returns always null

```
        var extDirs = Context.GetExternalFilesDirs("");
        if (extDirs != null && extDirs.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var extDir in extDirs)
            {
                var directories = extDir.ListFiles();
                ...
```

Read_External_Storage and Write_External_Storage are checked and

```
       extDir.CanRead() = True
       extDir.IsDirectory = True
       extDir.AbsolutePath = "/storage/5CD7-B286/Android/data/UnoPlatform.UnoPlatform/files"
```

This is my AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Can someone helps me?

Comment: I'm testing the app into Samsung Galaxy A7 with Android 10.0

Comment: How did you obtain that path? By GetExternalFilesDirs() ? Often an USB OTG drive will not be accessable using a classic file system path but only using SAF. If UnoPlatform.UnoPlatform is indeed your app specific path you do not need permissions at all.

Comment: @blackapps yes UnoPlatform.UnoPlatform is the name of my app. 
I obtain the path 
Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDirs("")

Comment: If there are no files to list you should get an empty array and not null. But who knows... Are there files in it?

Comment: yes, full of directories and files

Comment: This should indeed work. Could you please add a screenshot of the contents of the `UnoPlatform.UnoPlatform` folder in File explorer on Android? What about other paths that you get from `GetExternalFilesDirs`, does any of them contain your files?

Comment: @MartinZikmund in this link you can find the screenshot we.tl/t-DEs038CgT7 I'd like to show the folder in root /storage/5CD7-B286 Is it possible?

Comment: I see a different ID there in the screenshot (4EDA-FC5E). Is it possible that you have both SD card and the external USB drive plugged in?

Comment: @MartinZikmund apologize me. In the screenshot I have inserted another USB pendrive with much folders. To solve my problem I navigate .Parent folder untill /storage folder

Comment: Can you post your solution here as answer :-)  ? So that the question can be closed

Answer (score 1):

The fault was mine because Android creates a new folders path into external USB stick like this:

> /Android/data/UnoPlatform.UnoPlatform/files

and when I request GetExternalFilesDirs("") it returns null because "files" folder is empty.

So I navigated parents folders untill I found "storage" folder as a parent and then I showed it.

I think that it ins't a best practice to do, but at the moment this is the best solution for my business.

Answer (score 0):

For newer android version you need to call the following as well:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);
```

You have to request run time permission.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).